# Turn off marginal distribution axes on jointplot using seaborn package

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I like this particular plot and the ability to pass a function to the stat_func keyword to quickly plot up and visualize relationships between variables, but there's one thing. How do I 'turn off' or not plot the marginal distribution axes?

It looks nice but sometime I don't want this feature.

For example using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.arange(100) + np.random.randn(100)*20
y = np.arange(100) + np.random.randn(100)*20
sns.jointplot(x, y, kind='reg')
```

How can I remove the kde subplots on the top and right hand side of the main axes?

Comment: Well, isn't that just a simple scatter plot then?

Comment: It would have the regression line and it's range shaded for the specified confidence interval as well as the Pearson correlation coefficient and p value in this case.

Comment: isn't that just `sns.regplot`?

Comment: Yes minus the correlation coefficient. I mean I could do that myself but I was just wondering if this could be done simply using the function.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `JointGrid` directly:

```
from scipy import stats

g = sns.JointGrid(x, y, ratio=100)
g.plot_joint(sns.regplot)
g.annotate(stats.pearsonr)
g.ax_marg_x.set_axis_off()
g.ax_marg_y.set_axis_off()
```

[image]