# Turn off x-axis marginal distribution axes on jointplot using seaborn package

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032027/turn-off-marginal-distribution-axes-on-jointplot-using-seaborn-package), however I fail to adapt the provided solutions to my case.

I want to have a jointplot with `kind=hex` while removing the marginal plot of the x-axis as it contains no information. In the linked question the suggestion is to use JointGrid directly, however Seaborn then seems to to be unable to draw the hexbin plot.

```
joint_kws = dict(gridsize=70)
g = sns.jointplot(data=all_data, x="Minute of Hour", y="Frequency", kind="hex", joint_kws=joint_kws)
plt.ylim([49.9, 50.1])
plt.xlim([0, 60])
g.ax_joint.axvline(x=30,ymin=49, ymax=51)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image: resulting figure]

1. How to remove the margin plot over the x-axis?
2. Why is the vertical line not drawn?
3. Also is there a way to exchange the right margin to a plot which more clearly resembles the density?

edit: [Here is a sample of the dataset (33kB).](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QtmYwpJDHKH7T_W4-uyC8v-DY0jZKDv9/view?usp=sharing) Read it with `pd.read_pickle("./data.pickle")`

Answer (score 3):

I've been fiddling with an analog problem (using a scatterplot instead of the hexbin). In the end, the solution to your first point is awkwardly simple. Just add this line :

```
g.ax_marg_x.remove()
```

Regarding your second point, I've no clue as to why no line is plotted. But a workaround seems to be to use `vlines` instead :

```
g.ax_joint.vlines(x=30, ymin=49, ymax=51)
```

Concerning your last point, I'm afraid I haven't understood it. If you mean increasing/reducing the margin between the subplots, you can use the `space` argument stated [in the doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html#seaborn.jointplot).